# Customer wants to use a new sending domain but with the same IP - will this require an additional SAP package?

Tags: marketing-cloud, deliverability, sender-authentication-package, sap, ip-warming

I'm not sure of the answer to this, but the customer has already gone through IP warming/etc. - they have a dedicated IP address and an authenticated domain already.  They're spinning up a new company and therefore want to set up a NEW sending domain to send from.  If the customer sets this up on the same IP address, IP warming will obviously not be needed, I assume.  But, will they need to purchase a new SAP package for this new domain?

Comment: Let me know if my answer was helpful to you, by accepting it. If not,eat me know if you need any more input on this topic

Comment: @LukasLunow sorry man!  Got busy.  Thank you so much.  Great answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It might be useful to list few differences (and similarities) between SAP and a Private Domain, prior to getting to the point.

Sender Authentication Package (SAP) is best thought of as an account
“branding” tool. It gives you the ability to have your links and
images reflect the same branding as the authenticated domain you’ll
be sending mail from. SAP is actually a collection of products
including:

- Private Domain with link and image wrapping,
- Dedicated IP Address
- Reply Mail Management (RMM).

While these other products can purchased individually, the link and image wrapping that truly “brands” the account only comes with SAP. This grouping of products cannot be “broken up” - i.e. you can’t implement only the IP address but not the domain. Differences between a Private Domain purchased as part of an SAP, and purchased separately, are following:

- An SAP Private Domain includes link-wrapping (i.e. links, images, and anything else that would normally reflect SFMC, will reflect the chosen SAP domain instead).  The domain is also authenticated with SPF/Sender ID and DKIM/Domain Keys.
- A Private Domain which is purchased separately for sending is an
  authenticated domain for use in the From address only.  It is set up
  either via a User or Sender Profile, and this type of Private Domain
  DOES NOT include link-wrapping.  It has an MX record, SPF/Sender ID
  and DKIM/Domain Keys.

Additionally (outside of the from-email address context) both of the Private Domains listed above, can be used for creating branded domains for Cloud Pages. Neither of the Private Domains come with an IP address.

**In your case**, where your client has an existing SAP, including an IP address and a Private Domain, you can easily add (when purchased) another Private Domain to authenticate additional from-email address. No additional IP address will be provided with this new Private Domain, neither is it needed.

Do keep in mind, that links and image URLs will still reflect the SAP domain, and will NOT change, when sending emails from this new Private Domain. This is due to the limitation of a single SAP (hence only single link wrapping domain) per Business Unit. This is also why an additional SAP is not needed.

If they decide for a new Business Unit, my advice will be indeed to purchase a new SAP - so links and images reflect the branding correctly, but keep the IP address already in use on existing BU and being used for sending from the SAP domain.

What is worth noting, when deciding on a new Private Domain on a Business Unit with an existing SAP, is the DMARC authentication. Let's assume your client is sending from email.example.com today:

- SAP domain populates the bounce domain: bounce.email.example.com
- Your new private domain populates the from domain: brand2.com
- **DMARC fails** because example.com does not equal brand2.com

What would work:

- SAP domain populates the bounce domain: bounce.email.example.com
- Private domain populates the from domain: brand2.example.com
- **DMARC passes** because in both cases they use the domain example.com

So in the past this was only safe if all domains involved were part of the same domain name - or if you did not implement DMARC on those domains. There is a new feature called multi-bounce domain. When that is enabled, the system will always change the bounce domain setting to be bounce.[from domain] - like this:

- From domain: brand2.com
- Bounce domain auto-set to: bounce.brand2.com

Hence you can use a PD different from your SAP domain. Multi bounce is enabled upon request, by submitting a support case requesting help setting up multi-bounce domain support for your new private domain.